# How to Export Dataframes to Excel Workbook as Sheets with For Loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export, export-to-excel

I've written a code that runs through a for loop to generate data into dataframes but I want to export this data to a single workbook rather than multiple workbooks (actual code is on work computer and work stuff is confidential so dummy code is below)

Below is a general idea of how the code runs without the actual details of how the dataframes are composed. (Dummy code is running on csv files I pulled off Yahoo Finance)

```
FileName_List = ["AAPL", "GME", "MSFT", "NTDOY", "Z"]

for FileName in FileName_List:
    ReadName = FileName + ".csv"
    Raw_Data = pd.read_csv(ReadName, sep = ",")
  
    # removed code that actually manipulates data as it's not needed for example purposes and alludes to confidential data

    Raw_Data.to_excel("Final_Output.xlsx", sheet_name = FileName)
```

So now my directory has a bunch of Excel. I could manually just move them all into a single work book but with the actual amount of files I'll be running through, it would be just a time waste to do that.

I would want the end of my code to run everything to the same workbook and each sheet named with the for loop

The files land as is in separate files, so I can't change how the files hit. Again the above sample code is not actually the real number of files this code will have to run though

I've also tried using `ExcelWriter` but after the first loop it errors ask asking for a zipfile format using example code I found here: https://www.statology.org/write-multiple-excel-sheets-pandas/

Comment: So you write the dataframe twice? Once without manipulation and the second time is after the dataframe was manipulated?

Comment: @Marcelo Paco No I just didn't put code in to manipulate it because the code is on my work computer and data is confidential. I put a comment in my saying to pretend there was actual code there that transformed the data. In the real code I'm doing a lot of data manipulation (mainly formatting)

Comment: Remove one `to_excel` call and just leave the comment where you mention that left out the code that manipulates the data. It is less confusing that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DataFrame.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) says the following when wanting to create more that one sheet in a workbook:

> If you wish to write to more than one sheet in the workbook, it is
> necessary to specify an ExcelWriter object:
>
> ```
> df2 = df1.copy()
> with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
>     df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
>     df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
> ```

So taking the code mentioned above and applying it to your code it would like this:

```
FileName_List = ["AAPL", "GME", "MSFT", "NTDOY", "Z"]
# Create ExcelWriter object
df_list = []
for FileName in FileName_List:
    ReadName = FileName + ".csv"
    Raw_Data = pd.read_csv(ReadName, sep = ",")


    # PRETEND THAT THERE'S CODE HERE THAT ACTUALLY MANIPULATES THE DATA
    # Append to df list
    df_list.append(Raw_Data)

with pd.ExcelWriter('Final_Output.xlsx') as writer:
    for FileName, df in zip(FileName_List, df_list):
        # Write to excel sheet with writer object
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=FileName)
```

**Note**: you want to manipulate your dataframes first and append them into a list. Once that is done, you want to write them into a excel workbook in one go as multiple worksheets.

Comment: This code only produces a single sheet. My guess is the for loop is still overwriting the sheets previous sheets because it ends on "Z", which is the final file in the for loop. I'm also not understanding the comment to remove the 'to_excel' command. I thought you needed that even access the write function

Comment: @Emm, I don't quite understand how that can be happening. Let's chat in the python room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! I really appreciate the extra time you spent to sort out my issue!

Comment: See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253184/room-for-marcelo-paco-and-emm for th related discussion.